# How to change search results theme?

Tags: 6, search

I have a website that I need to add search functionality to. First though, we are running Drupal 6 with multiple sites each with its own theme. Content goes to its respective site by URL and the [Themekey](https://www.drupal.org/project/themekey) module. So for example:

```
example.com/site1 - First site and its content, theme 1
example.com/site2 - Second site, theme 2
example.com/site3 - Third site, theme 3
example.com - Primary base website. None of the above content, but everything else. Base theme.
```

This system has worked well for us though most developers say it's unusual.

I'm using the **[Custom Search module](https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_search)**. `example.com` has a search box and it searches all of the sites. I've put a search box on site1 `example.com/site1` and it's configured to only search site1's content types. But when you enter some criteria and click search `/site1` is dropped from the URL and so you end up in the base theme `example.com` because the URL becomes `example.com/search/node/some-criteria.` What I need is for the search results to stay in site1 theme.

Putting `/site1` in the results page url would keep the theme but I can't figure out how to do that. Maybe there is something in Themekey that will work but I have not been able to figure out either. Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure if you are already aware of [Drupal 6 end-of-life announcement](https://www.drupal.org/drupal-6-eol). I suggest you start thinking about Drupal 7 or 8.

Comment: @NoSssweat Yes I know, we're building our new sites in D7. But I work for a small nonprofit so this site is stuck in D6 for now...